# Separate PHP variables on file placed on another domain

Tags: php

I have a `PHP function` that rotates some images and other variables.

What I would like to do is to write those variables on another file, hosted on another domain and use them on my function.

**This is my function (without variables):**

```
$percent_arr = array();
foreach($block as $k => $_l) {
    $percent_arr = array_merge($percent_arr, array_fill(0, $_l['percent'], $k));
}
$random_key = $percent_arr[mt_rand(0,count($percent_arr)-1)];


$theblock = $block[$random_key]['block'];
$theblock2 = $block[$random_key]['tracking'];

 echo $theblock . ' »» ' . $theblock2;
```

**These are the variables that I would like to place on another file (hosted on other domain):**

```
 $src1 = '1.jpg'; 
 $src2 = '2.jpg'; 
$block[1] = array('block' => $src1 , 'percent' => 50, 'track' => '1');
$block[2] = array('block' => $src2 , 'percent' => 50, 'track' => '2');
```

Is this possible, how?

Comment: how are variables rotated?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

On your remote domain:

```
<?php

$src1 = '1.jpg'; 
$src2 = '2.jpg'; 

$blocks =
[
    '1' => ['block' => $src1 , 'percent' => 50, 'track' => '1'],
    '2' => ['block' => $src2 , 'percent' => 50, 'track' => '2']
];

$serialized = serialize($blocks);
echo $serialized;
```

On your other:

```
$blocks = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://example.com/path/to/blocks.php'));
```

However, you'll probably want to cache the fetch.  Because it could be blocking.

Comment: bog standard json is safer then serialize, though it's unlikely the domain would be hijacked at least you cant [execute crafted code](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/PHP_Object_Injection)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you're basically asking about either [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get) or [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) (if in doubt, stick to the former). You can use [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to help with encoding:

```
$src1 = '1.jpg'; 
$src2 = '2.jpg';

$block = [
    1 => ['block' => $src1 , 'percent' => 50, 'track' => '1'],
    ['block' => $src2 , 'percent' => 50, 'track' => '2']
];

$url = 'https://example.com/blah.php?' . http_build_query(['your_name_here' => $block]);
```

```
https://example.com/blah.php?your_name_here%5B1%5D%5Bblock%5D=1.jpg&your_name_here%5B1%5D%5Bpercent%5D=50&your_name_here%5B1%5D%5Btrack%5D=1&your_name_here%5B2%5D%5Bblock%5D=2.jpg&your_name_here%5B2%5D%5Bpercent%5D=50&your_name_here%5B2%5D%5Btrack%5D=2
```

Decoding happens automatically:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

```
Array
(
    [your_name_here] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [block] => 1.jpg
                    [percent] => 50
                    [track] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [block] => 2.jpg
                    [percent] => 50
                    [track] => 2
                )

        )

)
```